# Understanding Dispose method for in-memory database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, dispose

I have this base class for all my unit tests that spins up an in-memory database

```
public abstract class TestWithSqlite : IDisposable
{
    private const string InMemoryConnectionString = "DataSource=:memory:";
    private readonly SqliteConnection _connection;

    protected readonly ToDoDbContext DbContext;

    protected TestWithSqlite()
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection(InMemoryConnectionString);
        _connection.Open();
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ToDoDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(_connection)
                .Options;
        DbContext = new ToDoDbContext(options);
        DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

My question is: If I call `DbContext.something` in one of my tests, is it the `Dispose` method that ensures that this instance of the database is closed when the test ends? So that for the next test when I call DbContext again, its a new instance?

Comment: What testing Framework do you use? Does it ensure there is only one test per class? Does it guarantee that `.Dispose()` will be called on your test class?

Comment: Why would dispose drop a database? If the docs of sqlite in-mem db says so than yeah, but I highly doubt that. Normally `Dispose` tells the db context that you are done using the connection.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm using xUnit - each test class can have multiple tests. No, it doesn't ensure `.Dispose()` is called - that's what my query was - do I need to call it explicitly at the of each test to  ensure test db data don't bleed over?

Comment: @Silvermind sorry i meant close the db not drop it. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Every unit test should have a new DbContext.  You don't want any dependencies between tests.  Therefore, calling dispose at the end of a test is correct.

Comment: But my question is does dispose get called automatically after each test is done running? Nowhere am I having to call it manually in my test.

Comment: @blankface - You must explicitly call it. Nothing will do it for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity how is calling `.Dispose()` calling any different from a custom method I write that calls `_connection.Close()` - isn't the end goal to close the connection at the end of the day?

Comment: Close doesn't have to dispose objects, it could just 'close the connection', which may then allow the connection to be reopened.

Comment: @blankface - When a child is misbehaving you could ask them to stop or you could beat them severely. What's the difference? After all isn't the end goal to get them to stop misbehaving?

Comment: @Enigmativity  that is one heavy analogy but I think you've made your point haha

Answer (score 1):

The [xUnit documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#constructor) describes this. So the class containing your tests could implement `IDisposable`. By default, xUnit will run every method in your test class in isolation, and will call `Dispose`, so any object instances are unique per test.

If you want to share object instances, you can use fixtures, but it sounds like you want isolation between your tests, which is there by default.

So if you now directly add test methods to the class in your question, the context should be unique for each test. You should be able to test that by putting breakpoints in your test methods (or `Dispose`) and then debug the tests, to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

When I take a look into "SQLite.Net Help the document states:
Dispose - Disposes and finalizes the connection, if applicable.

In other words all SQLiteConnection Members become invalid, all resources are released.
Regards
Martin

Comment: The OP is calling `connection.Close()`, not `connection.Dispose()`. Can you please be clear what happens then?

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong. When one calls Close all commands linked to this connection are reset.

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong. When one closes a connection all commands linked to this connection are reset. However the connection is remains available  - you can open this connection and e.g. execute other queries. The Close command verifies that you have no pendig changes to the database, it closes the file and frees the sqlite3 data structure; else you get a Busy error..

Answer (score 0):

Since your test class is used for multiple tests, having a base class for things that should be unique to one test is a bad idea.

You want to control *exactly* when and how a database is opened and when and how it's removed from memory.

That means your class should not be inherited, but rather used by each single test.

Make your class a normal class that can be instantiated and will provide a DBContext through a method or property. Open and create the database in the constructor, close and remove the database in the dispose method as you already do.

Your test should start with a `using` block that instantiates this class.

Inside the using block your tests can use the class and the DBContext it provides. the using block will take care of the dispose, no matter how you leave your test (the code might throw an exception after all).

I don't remember how it worked, but I think you can give names to the in-memory databases. It might be a good idea to do so, otherwise you will have to make sure your tests never run in parallel.